# AC circuit design and current flow

Tags: current, ac, circuit-analysis, circuit-design

Let's say I have a simple series circuit with an AC voltage source connected to a "very strong" resistor which is connected to a little LED light and then back to the source. From what I understand, with an AC source, the current is constantly changing direction.  Does that mean that the LED will only produce light (heat) when the current is going counter-clockwise (i.e. going through the LED before the resistor)? What will happen to the LED during the half cycle that is not producing light?

**EDIT 1**

I think my example with a LED was bad.  Let's say a light bulb (simple R) is connected through the circuit instead of the LED.  Does that mean that it will only glow when the current goes into one of the two directions (because the current will be "stopped/resisted" first in the other direction)?

Comment: Nonsense like "very strong" resistor doesn't belong here.  You should also be able to see that "counter-clockwise" is meaningless since you haven't said which way the LED is connected.

Comment: The LED will only produce light when when it's forward biased; that is, when the anode is positive with respect to the cathode. When the AC changes polarity the LED will become reverse biased, and if the AC voltage is high enough, it'll destroy the diode.  Also, to get meaningful answers,  You should add the value of the resistor and the value of the AC voltage to your question.

Comment: See this question http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/205698/ac-circuit-parallel-resonant-band-stop-filter for background on what this question is regarding.

Answer (score 1):

> a "very strong" resistor

You probably mean a resistor with "high" resistance. There is something called a "strong" pull-up/down resistor in electronics, but that actually refers to a low resistance.

> Does that mean that the LED will only produce light (heat) when the current is going counter-clockwise (i.e. going through the LED before the resistor)? What will happen to the LED during the half cycle that is not producing light?

A LED is a semiconductor which consists of a single p-n junction. When forward biased ("correct" polarization), the diode emits light when electrical energy is applied to it (electroluminescence). When the junction is reverse biased no light will be produced, but that has nothing to do with the physical position of the resistor.
Depending on the voltage (and the resistor), the LED can potentially be damaged when reverse voltage is applied (breakdown).

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly run LED's from AC voltage. But in the negative cycle, it won't glow.

You can put strings of LED's in series and apply AC voltage across it. Make sure that no more than 3.5V appears across a single LED. There you have it.
If you want the whole thing to glow in both cycle; make a mirror circuit of the same thing.
Positive Cycle - String 1 will glow
Negative Cycle - String 2 will glow

There are a lot of tutorials online. It's your turn now.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to "Edit 1", switching the LED to an incandescent lamp.

No, the lamp will light on every AC Cycle, there is no directionality that the lamp can see.  You are talking about a series circuit, the same current flows through all elements equally, and since the resistor and lamp are both pure resistances (not semiconductors), the lamp will light as long as sufficient current passes through it (no matter the 'direction').